# How to hide Boostrap Dropdown submenu when other menu of dropdown is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying bootstrap dropdownmenu and on click of any parent dropdown value i am displaying other child dropdown. when i click on a value in dropdown ,the childmenu opens and when i click on next dropdown value ,the previous chidmenu dropdown is not closed.I want to close the previous childdropdown menu if any other value of parent menu is clicked.How to achieve this?Please help! Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul id="ddlTest" class="ddltestdd dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.testresults)
        {
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@item.Text</span>
                <span class="testCaret" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;">
                </span>
                <ul class="ddltestdd dropdown-menu dropup" role="menu" id="testorder_@item.Text">
                    <li>
                        <span class="TestBySubmenu">T1</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="TestBySubmenu">T2</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var testText;
                    $(".dropdown-submenu").click(function () {
                            $(this).find(".dropdown-submenu").removeClass('open');
                    $(".dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu").css('display', 'block');
                    testText;= $(this).text();
                    return false;
                });



        $('.dropdown-menu li span').click(function () {

        var Allowpageload = testText;
        if ((Allowpageload == "T1") || (Allowpageload == "T2")) {
          //load page
            $(".dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu").css('display', 'none');
            $('[id^="testorder_]').dropdown('toggle');
            $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your code I think you aren't arranging the classes properly for it to work. I have got a good example for the submenu here:

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/yxkut/16/)

your first `<li> tag` shouldn't have the `dropdown submenu` it has there. Instead it is your embedded `ul` tag that should have it

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul id="ddlTest" class="ddltestdd dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.testresults)
        {
            <li>
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@item.Text</span>
                <span class="testCaret" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;">
                </span>
                <ul class="ddltestdd dropdown-menu dropup sub-menu" role="menu" id="testorder_@item.Text">
                    <li>
                        <span class="TestBySubmenu">T1</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="TestBySubmenu">T2</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```